# bash: find all files in directory and sub-directories which the first letter inside file is z or Z

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to count all of the files in current directory and in its sub-directories that the first letter inside the file (grep???) is z or Z?

tried to use grep, head and such but didn't succed

Comment: What have you already tried? Not a code writing service.  Show your work! :p

Comment: until now i only managed to get a list of all files and and from here i got only the first line of the first file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# find all the files (replace directory with the path to your folder)
find directory -type f | \

# read each file path
while read -r f; do 
    # read the first character of the file
    read -rn1 c < $f

    # if the 1 character matches eith Z or z, then echo the path
    [[ "$c" =~ Z|z ]] && echo $f
done | \

# count them
wc -l

# here's a one line version:
find directory -type f | while read -r f; do read -rn1 c < $f; [[ "$c" =~ Z|z ]] && echo $f; done | wc -l
```

Comment: thank you ,solved my problem :)

Comment: You're welcome. It was a fun puzzle. :)

Answer (score 0):

grep has a -c option which returns the count of hits it found.

Comment: but i need to look only on the first word in each file... how can i adjust grpe -c to look in first letter of every file in my directory

Comment: use a regular expression:   grep -lRe '^[z|Z]' *.<whatever> -c (sorry forgot about your subdirectories)